# Teechart: bottom axes label angle

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

I'm using Teechart for .net V3.

When trying to rotate the X-labels to 45° some of the labels are not displayed, but if the angle is set to 90° it is OK.

Please see the following images:

**This is 45° rotation:**
[image: 45° rotation]

**This is 90° rotation:**
[image]

Is it possible to show all the labels with 45° angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use custom labels to achieve all labels appear when you use an angle of 45º. You can do something as next code:

```
private Steema.TeeChart.TChart tChart1; 
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  tChart1 = new Steema.TeeChart.TChart();
  this.Controls.Add(tChart1);
  tChart1.Left = 100;
  tChart1.Top = 50;
  tChart1.Width = 500;
  tChart1.Height = 350; 
  tChart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 
  InitialzieChart(); 
}
private void InitialzieChart()
{
  Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar bar1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar(tChart1.Chart);
  DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
  Random rnd = new Random();
  bar1.XValues.DateTime = true; 
  //bar1.date
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
  {
    bar1.Add(dt, rnd.Next(100));
    dt = dt.AddDays(5); 
  }

  tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Angle = 45;
  tChart1.Panel.MarginLeft = 10;
  tChart1.Legend.Alignment = Steema.TeeChart.LegendAlignments.Bottom; 
  AddCustomLabels(); 
}
private void AddCustomLabels()
{
  tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Items.Clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < tChart1[0].Count; i++)
  {
    tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Items.Add(tChart1[0].XValues[i], DateTime.FromOADate(tChart1[0].XValues[i]).ToLongDateString()); 
  }
}
```

Could you tell us if previous code works in your end?

Thanks,